# Rails - will_paginate has broken link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, will-paginate

I've added the will_paginate gem, and it's working fine on all other areas of site. However, whenever I try clicking in the 'Show' links in the view, to link to the order, it's giving me this error message: *
The @orders variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?*

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it? I've tried restarting the server. Thanks!!

View code:

```
<h3>Your Orders:</h3>
<table class="order-items">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Order No.</th>
  <th>View Order</th>
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></td>
    <td><%= order.id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show',  order_path(order) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>   
</table>

<p><%= will_paginate @orders %></p>
```

Controller Code:

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@orders = @customer.orders.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'id desc',
  per_page: 5
```

Routes:

```
resources :orders

resources :customers

get 'admin' => 'admin#index'

get 'account' => 'customers#show'

match '/account', :to => 'customers#show'

match'/signup', :to => 'customers#new'

controller :sessions do
  get  'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end


resources :users

resources :line_items

resources :carts

get "store/index"

resources :products do
  get :who_bought, on: :member
end

resources :line_items do
  put 'decrease', on: :member
  put 'increase', on: :member
end

root to: 'store#index', as: 'store'
```

Comment: Try inverting how you search for orders, like this: **@orders = Order.find_all_by_customer_id(@customer.id).paginate page: params[:page], order: 'id desc', per_page: 5**

Comment: That occurs after you click Show? What's in the show controller method and its view?